# Would it be sensible / viable to give gnuplot its own stack?

Tags: discussion

I see there are a fair few (~8k on a grand total of 1 million) [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) questions on SO, but wouldn't it be a good idea to give it its own stack so knowledge is more centralized and easier to find?

My thoughts:

- When looking for gnuplot issues, SO is not the site that spontaneously springs to mind. Similar to LATEX it is a very specific tool.
- The sheer amount of questions on SO overwhelm the number of gnuplot questions. (1 million / 8k).

What do you think, is it a good idea to create a proposal on area51?

Comment: Probably not. Who should go changing over to that community. A tag is just fine.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mysticial I am aware of area51. The reason for this question is that the majority of the gnuplot questions is probably currently found on SO. It is useless in my opinion to propose an alternative stack if there is no support from the SO community.

Comment: So you want a new site without going through the A51 process? Very few sites have done that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because the ratio gnuplot/total questions on SO is very low, less than 1%, I think a lot of potential gnuplot questions will just too quickly disappear from the front page and draw too little attention.

Comment: @Mysticial no, I want to know if the SO people, that currently see the majority of the gnuplot questions, think it is a good idea. If a quick question on meta tells me it is a bad idea, then I won't go through the effort of proposing it on area51.

Comment: @jippie Most (experienced) people are usually not using the front page to watch out for questions, but tag filtered incoming queues.

Answer (score 6):

> When looking for gnuplot issues, SO is not the site that spontaneously springs to mind.

And it shouldn't be. Google should be the site that springs to mind.  It shows where gnuplot issues similar to yours are dealt with. For example, I tried googling "gnuplot error bars" and two of the top five hits were from Stack Overflow.

> The sheer amount of questions on SO overwhelm the number of gnuplot questions. (1 million / 8k).

10  million, and it doesn't really matter. The [gnuplot tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnuplot) is what matters to those who want to answer gnuplot questions.